# Recursively turn table data into JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I need to turn a table that looks like this:

```
    <table class="pie-chart-data" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>has_title</th>
                <th>has_value</th>
                <th>has_details</th>
                <th>has_overflow</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Cycling</td>
                <td rowspan="3">2</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Consecetitur</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Skating</td>
                <td rowspan="3">3</td>
                <td>Lorem</td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    <table border="1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>has_title</th>
                                <th>has_value</th>
                                <th>has_details</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="3">Cycling</td>
                                <td rowspan="3">2</td>
                                <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Consecetitur</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dolor</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Into JSON that looks like this:

```
var data = [
                {
                    title: 'Cycling',
                    value: 2,
                    details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                },
                {
                    title: 'Skating',
                    value: 3,
                    details: ['Lorem ipsum', 'Dolor sit amet', 'Extra information area']
                },
                {
                    title: 'Other',
                    value: 1,
                    overflow: [
                        {
                            title: 'Overflow 1',
                            value: 1,
                            details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Overflow 2',
                            value: 3,
                            details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Climbing',
                    value: 4,
                    details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                },
                {
                    title: 'Kayaking',
                    value: 2,
                    details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                },
                {
                    title: 'Skydiving',
                    value: 5,
                    details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                },
                {
                    title: 'Rowing',
                    value: 2,
                    details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                },
                {
                    title: 'Rowing',
                    value: 3,
                    details: ['186 unique individuals', '2.2% of total', 'Extra information area']
                }
            ];
```

The number of detail items can vary, so I presume I'll need to look at the rowspan attribute and infer where the next values will be. Also, the table that exists within a 'td' will be nested into an 'overflow' property, so I also presume I'll need to use recursion to extract the key/values from these nested tables.

Can somebody point me in the right direction for doing this?

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML output? Could you write a script to output the data in JSON to begin with?

Comment: I'd probably advise you to produce the JSON manually. A programmatic method is likely to be far too complicated.

Comment: I was suspecting that would be the case - the solution I'm trying to code is looking pretty complex. I do have control over the HTML output, but I like the idea of having a table that will display in a readable way before being processed as JSON, so was hoping to avoid simplifying it.

Comment: Ideally you want the data in JSON and then produce the table from that...